# Rank generating functions on a graded poset and a linear extension of it

Tags: generating-functions, posets, algebraic-combinatorics

Let $A$ be a possibly infinite ensemble and let $\leq$ be a partial order between elements of $A$. We denote $P_{\leq}=(A,\leq)$ the corresponding poset. Furthermore, we suppose that $P$ is graded, i.e. there exists a rank funtion $r:A\to\mathbb{N}$ on $P_\leq$.

Now let $P_{\leq_\ast}$ be a linear extension of $P_\leq$, i.e. any two elements of $P_{\leq_\ast}$ are comparable and $a\leq b\Rightarrow a \leq_\ast b$. Furthermore, let $\ell:A\to\mathbb{N}$ be a rank function on $P_{\leq_\ast}$.

Now define the two ordinary generating functions:
\begin{eqnarray}
g_\ell(z)&=&\sum_{a:a\in A}z^{\ell(a)},\\
g_r(z)&=&\sum_{a:a\in A}z^{r(a)},\\
\end{eqnarray}
Is there a direct relation between $g_\ell(z)$ and $g_r(z)$ ? If so, how can I go from one to the other ? If not, what additional information do I need in order to transform one into the other ?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: The only information about the poset contained in the generating function $g_\ell$ is the cardinality of $A$.

Comment: So there is no way to go from $g_\ell$ to $g_r$ or back ? Also what then is the information about the poset that is contained in $g_r$ ?